# Real Time Update of Devexpress Gauges

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have managed to create a circular guage using Devepxress following their code examples but I have a problem. Once the control is created I do not no how to use their function to update the controls.

They do have an example of how to use a updatepanel so I am considering my best option would be to add an updatepanel dynamically but how would i attach it to each control that is created so its only that one guage that would change its values

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11286

Form Load Code :

```
dgh.CreateCircularGauge(25, pnlTorgue);
dgh.CreateCircularGauge(45, pnlRpm);
dgh.CreateCircularGauge(75, pnlSpeedkmh);
dgh.CreateThemomenter(85, pnlEngTemp);
```

**What i want from this question **

Is Ability to say dgh.CreatCircularGuage(oldValue, NewValue , UpdateBoolean,mypanel);
So that I could call this using a aspxtimer tick event ? is this possible

```
public  void CreateCircularGauge(int guageValue, Panel mypanel)
{
        // Creates a new instance of the ASPxGaugeControl class with default settings.
        ASPxGaugeControl gaugeControl = new ASPxGaugeControl();
        gaugeControl.EnableCallbackAnimation = true;

        // Creates a new instance of the CircularGauge class and adds it
        // to the gauge control's Gauges collection.
        CircularGauge circularGauge = (CircularGauge)gaugeControl.AddGauge(GaugeType.Circular);

        // Adds the default elements (a scale, background layer, needle and spindle cap).
        circularGauge.AddDefaultElements();

        // Changes the background layer's paint style.
        ArcScaleBackgroundLayer background = circularGauge.BackgroundLayers[0];
        background.ShapeType = BackgroundLayerShapeType.CircularFull_Style2;

        // Customizes the scale's settings.
        ArcScaleComponent scale = circularGauge.Scales[0];
        scale.MinValue = 0;
        scale.MaxValue = 100;
        scale.Value = guageValue;
        scale.MajorTickCount = 6;
        scale.MajorTickmark.FormatString = "{0:F0}";
        scale.MajorTickmark.ShapeType = TickmarkShapeType.Circular_Style1_2;
        scale.MajorTickmark.ShapeOffset = -9;
        scale.MajorTickmark.AllowTickOverlap = true;
        scale.MinorTickCount = 3;
        scale.MinorTickmark.ShapeType = TickmarkShapeType.Circular_Style2_1;
        scale.AppearanceTickmarkText.TextBrush = new SolidBrushObject(Color.Gray);

        // Changes the needle's paint style.
        ArcScaleNeedleComponent needle = circularGauge.Needles[0];
        needle.ShapeType = NeedleShapeType.CircularFull_Style3;

        // Adds the gauge control to the Page.
        gaugeControl.Width = 250;
        gaugeControl.Height = 250;
        gaugeControl.AutoLayout = true;

        mypanel.Controls.Add(gaugeControl);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To update each gauge separately the best solution is to use the [ASPxGaugeControl.PerformCallback](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGaugesScriptsASPxClientGaugeControl_PerformCallbacktopic) method. You should call this method within the Timer client-side event and then handle the [ASPxGaugeControl.CustomCallback](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGaugesASPxGaugeControl_CustomCallbacktopic) event at server side to update gauge's value as it needed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var isDirty;
        function gaugePerformCallback() {
            var gauge = window['gauge'];
            isDirty = gauge.InCallback();
            if (!isDirty)
                gauge.PerformCallback();
        }
        function gaugeEndCallback() { 
            if (isDirty)
                window.setTimeout(function() { gaugePerformCallback() }, 0);
        }
</script>

...
<dx:ASPxGaugeControl runat="server" Width="250px" Height="250px" BackColor="Transparent" ID="gaugeControl" ClientInstanceName="gauge"
    SaveStateOnCallbacks="false">
    <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="gaugeEndCallback" />
    ...
</dx:ASPxGaugeControl >
<dx:ASPxTimer ID="timer" runat="server" Interval="500">
    <ClientSideEvents Tick="function(s, e) {
                gaugePerformCallback();
         }"></ClientSideEvents>
</dx:ASPxTimer>
```

Server-side code-behind:

```
void gaugeControl_CustomCallback(object source, DevExpress.Web.CallbackEventArgsBase e) {
    gaugeControl.Value = /* value */;
}
```

Comment: This wont work with the method I am using above though so it wont  I am buidling the controls within code but I will try your solution and if it works adaapet to that